# ¿Por qué no se cambia el state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy usando un state para manejar el valor de visualizar, y según su valor se muestre en el div diferentes pantallas, pero a la hora de pulsar los botones para que se cambie el numero de la ventana no funciona. os dejo el código. El numero 1 lo muestra, pero al pulsar los botones no lo cambia.

intente usar en vez de states variables locales y cambiarlas con una función pero tampoco funcionaba. hay mas código pero la pagina me pedía reconquistarlo que puse lo relacionado con el tema.

```
const Perfil = () => {
const [visualizar, guardarVisualizar] = useState(1);
    return (
        <div>
            <Layout>
                <>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-12">
                                    <h1 className="display-5 my-2">Perfil <span>{nombre}</span></h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <Divp1 className="mb-2 row">
                                <div className="col-12 col-lg-3">
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-12">
                                            <button
                                            type="button"
                                            onclick = {() => guardarVisualizar(1)}>
                                                <Label>Cuenta</Label>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr />
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-12">
                                            <BotonTodo
                                            type="button"
                                            onclick = {() => guardarVisualizar(2)}
                                            >
                                                <Label>Seguridad</Label>
                                            </BotonTodo>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr />
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-12">
                                            <BotonTodo 
                                            type="button"
                                            onclick = {() => guardarVisualizar(3)}>
                                                <Label>Eliminar Cuenta</Label>
                                            </BotonTodo>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <Divp2 className="con-12 col-lg-7">
                                {visualizar===1 ? (<h1> 1</h1>) : null}

                                {visualizar===2 ? (<h1> 2</h1>) : null}

                                {visualizar===3 ? (<h1> 3</h1>) : null}
                                </Divp2>

                            </Divp1>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            </Layout>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Perfil;
```

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en la consola? ¿De dónde sale el valor para `nombre` en la línea: `<h1 className="display-5 my-2">Perfil <span>{nombre}</span></h1>`?

Comment: @Orici esa informacion sale de una variable llamada Usuario, que saca lainformacion de firebase. y en la consola notengo nada, solo me sale los datos de usuario,que alli tengo un console.log para controlar

Comment: Ok, si tu problema no es muy evidente en el código que has puesto, no puedes recibir ayuda. Debes aportar un ejemplo mínimo verificable. En tu código se usan  variables sin definir lo que es de por si causa de error. Y varios componentes adicionales que *a priorí* no permitirían probar el código. Hay plataformas para hacer pruebas sencillas, tu problema puede resumirse así: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e4whn3

Comment: @Orici losiento por aportar tan pocos detalles, es la primera vez pregunto algo, pero si, el problema basico es ese, que pulso los botones y no cambia lo que se muestra en pantalla.

Comment: Ok. Tu problema es que usaste: `onclick` en lugar de `onClick` en los botones, que es la forma válida en *React*. Hay un error en la consola que lo advierte.

Comment: Tienes razon.... no me di cuenta hasta que entre en la herramienta de pruebas que pasaste. Muchas Gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 1):

Para que funciones tu método `onclick` deberas cambiar de `onclick` a `onClick`. (La letra **C** en mayúscula)

Recuerda que ReactJS representa el espacio de palabras con letras mayusculas.

Answer (score 0):

el código que aportas es un poco vago porque aporta muy poca información para poder tener una visión completa de lo que estas haciendo pero a simple vista este en el evento **onClick** recuerda que los eventos de **React** se nombran usando camelCase, en vez de minúsculas , por otro lado cuando hagas la función guardarVisualizar ya tiene implicita su ejecución por que como dije anteriormente es una función y alli usaras setState para actualizar el estado ,
ejemplo

```
const total = () => {
            setData(() => data)
        };
```

y luego solo llamas a esa función refernciandola no inicializandola.

```
onClick={total}
```